Why does my terminal return 'process exited with return value 3221225725'?
I am getting this mesaage every time I run my code:

process exited with return value 3221225725

Please someone help me.
Here's the code (a long list of primes to populate the vector omitted here for brevity):
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    vector <long long> Prime(664579);
    Prime = {2, 3, ...., 9999991};
}

I want my code to return a value of 0.

A few side notes, never include <bits/stdc++.h> include  and  instead. Avoid using using namespace.  And do not add lines like   ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);  cin.tie(NULL); which you probably copy pasted from a competitive coding site and are almost never needed in production code

3221225725 is a seg fault.  When you set the value for Prime, do you keep the .... or are those actual numbers?

As an aside, please read "Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?" and "Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?".

.... is certainly not valid. Please post your actual code. Also, get rid of the cin.tie and ios_base crap. The using namespace std. The stdc++.h ... Whatever resource you're using to learn from should be tossed out and never seen again.

Please read How to debug small programs and What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?. Also, please stop reading competitive programming websites.

Side note; never use NULL - nullptr exists and is superior in every way.

if you ask about code that exhibits unepected output we can help you with that. If you ask about code that causes compiler errors we can help you with that too. If you show us code that causes a compiler error and ask about other code that produces unexpected output we cannot help you.

Apart from not doing anything useful, your code looks more or less fine to me (except the bits/stdc++.h stuff, which is more or less harmless, and the .... part which remains a mystery).  What happens if you just have Prime = {2, 3, 5,7};.

@JesperJuhl vector <long long> Prime(664579); is pretty clear ;-)

There is no point in creating the vector with 664579 default elements just to reassign the whole vector with a different set of elements.

@Jabberwocky -- re: "not doing anything useful" -- it's demonstrating the problem, which is exactly what example code is supposed to do.

Exit code 3221225725 is 0xC00000FD in hex, which is how Microsoft Windows indicates STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW. (This code is system-specific, see Pete Becker's comment below.)
Essentially, your initializer list is too large. This is a known problem P2752R3, as explained here.
But the fix is currently supported only in GCC v14, see cppreference.
Anyway, as people have mentioned in comments to your question, never #include <bits/stdc++.h>, because the standard C++ does not have that header, see Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?.
Also, don't use using namespace std;, certainly never in headers, but preferably not in source code as well, see What's the problem with using namespace std;?.

Re: "which is STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW" -- maybe, but that's system-specific. It's not standard C++, which allows return values of only EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS, and 0, which is equivalent to EXIT_SUCCESS. Those return values are mapped to system-specific codes, but none of them represents a stack overflow. +1.

In general, when you see a number like 3221225725 that you don't recognize and feel is out-of-place, convert it to hexadecimal and see if it becomes more recognizable. If it seems to be presenting a word or phrase or is too regular, it could be the program trying to tell you something important. This applies to result codes and data values spotted in diagnostics or debugging. Here is a list of famous magic debug values.

I get what you are saying, but I would phrase it differently. The C++ Standard does allow values besides EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS, and 0 to be returned from main, however, it states that, for other values, "the status returned is implementation defined." In addition, the standard states that the values returned to the host environment when either EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE is returned are also implementation defined. See main function and Startup and termination.
